# Best JS Libraries for Checkbox/Faceted Search

Tags: javascript, .net, umbraco

I'm looking to re-create a checkbox/faceted search for a website and I was hoping to get some advice on what libraries to use.

The site is developed in .NET and sits on an Umbraco solution.

The site currently uses Knockout.js and Ajax to call the server with multiple requests, but I want to add routing (Knockout has none) so that the URL can be shared.

I plan on ripping out Knockout and starting from scratch. So does anyone know the best libraries to create a search which requires the following?

- URL can be copied which contains data relevant to the selected filters
- Multiple filters can be selected
- Upon selecting a filter, it automatically updates the view with relevant data
- Allows pagination

Any recommendations would be appreciated!

EDIT: Sorry I forgot to mention, I'm looking for front-end solutions as I'm currently searching with Examine on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try different options -

1) You can go for Elastic. It calls facets "aggregates" but supports some fairly detailed logic around them. It is pretty simple to understand and the documentation is so far good. There are several c# libraries you can use with it, I've tried NEST: [NEST](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NEST/5.0.0-beta1)

2) Another option would be to store content in RavenDB and uses facets on that: https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/csharp/client-api/commands/querying/how-to-work-with-facet-query

3) You can also try BOBO faceted search which is managed using Umbraco category. [Faceted search with BOBO](https://24days.in/umbraco-cms/2014/search-with-bobo/)

4) Some more options for you could be -

- [Xuntos Faceted Search (XFS)](https://www.xfssearch.com/about/)
- Solr is another option for you. Below are some links -

http://www.slideshare.net/e2-marketing/we-want-a-corporate-umbraco-platforms-errr-surecode-garden15-session

http://www.eduserv.org.uk/blog/2011/09/26/faceted-search-using-solr-what-it-is-and-what-benefits-does-it-provide/

http://www.alpha-solutions.us/products/umbraco-search-solution

- [Solis Search](https://www.solissearch.com/)

Hope these are helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Very helpful thank you. Quick question: any opinion/experience with Vue Routing? Edit: I forgot to mention. I'm more-so looking for something to work inline with Examine, so the front-end side of things.

Comment: Hi Sorry bro, not sure for this! If you like the answer you can also vote me up as well :) Thanks